# Textures list not shown

Tags: texturing, interface, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm completely new to blender (v 2.72b). I'm reading the official tutorial but I'm stuck because the list of textures isn't displayed inside texture context of properties menu.

[This](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Your_First_Animation/1.A_static_Gingerbread_Man#Materials_and_Textures) is the tutorial and in particular I can't see the texture list in [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/File:Manual-Part-I-Quick38v25.png) picture.

This is what I see in my project:

[image: blender screenshot]

What am I missing?

Comment: That's weird, does that happen with every other material? So, if you select another object that has another material, is the texture list also missing there, what about newly created materials?

Comment: As I said I'm completely new to blender, so I don't know what are exactly a material, a texture and the relationship between them, but if I select the plane below nothing changes (even if I enter the material context and add a new material).

Comment: Did you download a daily build or an official release from blender.org? I've never seen something like this, the texture list should be shown even on a new blend file. You should probably do another download and reinstall.

Comment: I tried with a new project and it's shown correctly! I'm using the official release (and I tried even with v2.70 and v2.60 but it's still the same using this project). I'll start again from zero a new project and let you know.

Comment: I started a new project and it all went well.